# how to replace more than one word in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

how can i replace more than one word in visual studio code

to replace a word inside a folder contains files i use

`ctrl` `shift` `H`

to replace a word inside a same file i use

`ctrl` `H`

the issue is i can only replace one word at a time is it possible to replace more than one word at the same time

like ::

```
search  [     numper1 , numper2       ]

replace [     numper0 , numper1       ]
files to include [   F:/*** FILE LOCATION   ]
```

if it possible please let me know - or if you have a plugin i can donwload please link it to me , i'd appreciate that

and if it possible in sublime to let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Replace Rules](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules) you can replace more than one item

```json
"replacerules.rules": {
    "Replace Multi": {
      "find": ["numper1","numper2"],
      "replace": ["numper0","numper1"]
    }
}
```

With [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) you can create a custom command with arguments

With [Command on All Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.commandOnAllFiles) you can apply the command on all files in the workspace.

```json
"multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.multiSearchReplace",
      "sequence": [
        { "command": "replacerules.runRule",
          "args": { "ruleName": "Replace Multi" }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "commandOnAllFiles.commands": {
    "Replace Multi": {
      "command": "multiCommand.multiSearchReplace",
      "includeFileExtensions": [".py"]
    }
  }
```

I will modify `Command on All Files` so you can select the command from a list.